# SAS left join getting more records than what in first table

Tags: sql, sas, proc

```
table a 
x    y               z
123  london          Data engineer
345  United states   Software engineer
678  South africa    Electrical engineer

Table b
X    U
123  David
345  Mike
910  Mark
678  Steve
121  Kyle

Output
X    Y              Z                   U
123  London         Data engineer       David
345  United states  Software engineer   Mike
678  South Africa   Electrical engineer Steve
```

when I use proc SQL left join as below I'm getting more than 3 records. Could you please help me

Proc SQL;

```
create table x as 
select 
      a.*,
      b.u 
   from 
      table a 
         left join table b 
            on a.x = b.x; 
quit;
```

Comment: The data you have posted works with the code you posted.  Can you post an example that re-produces the issue you are having?  Are there any values of X in B that appear multiple times?

Comment: yes the values of x in B appear multiple times

Comment: So which value of U  do you want to keep to get down to just one observation per value of X?

Comment: In table b it appears that value of column x is having multiple different value in another column is this making the record count more?

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If a `left join` returns more records than are in the original table, then you have duplicate values of the join variable in the right-hand table or query.

The common ways to solve this are:

- If the right hand table has multiple records per ID<sup>1</sup>, but they are guaranteed to have the same values for the variable(s) you are returning from that table, you can use `distinct` in a subquery to reduce them to a single record.

  `select * from a left join (select distinct x,y from b) b on a.x=b.x`
- If the right hand table is returning values where you'd like to summarize (say, use the `sum` or the `mean`) when you have multiple records, do so in a subquery, grouping by the ID variable(s).

  `select * from a left join (select x, sum(y) from b group by x) b on a.x=b.x`
- Otherwise, you will have to use some logic - either in the query, or before you join.  This is where doing this in the SAS data step can sometimes be better; for example, if you want the most recent value, it's a bit easier to pre-process that in a data step (SQL can also do that, but it's a more complicated, and often slower, query).

<sub><sup>1</sup> I use the term ID to refer to whatever you are joining the table on.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much